# Specify default hosts for a task if no roles/hosts were provided

Tags: fabric

I would like to define default host(s) for a specific task in case no roles or hosts were explicitly provided from the command line.
I can use `env.all_hosts` to check the lists of current hosts is empty, but I don't know how to set it to some host.

I also considered using `@hosts()`, but it seems to override the input from the command line, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `@hosts` decorator from the command line, using the command-line host lists, as described in the first point of [Fabric's Order of Precedence](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/execution.html#order-of-precedence):

> ## Order of precedence
>
> We’ve been pointing out which methods of setting host lists trump the others, as we’ve gone along. However, to make things clearer, here’s a quick breakdown:
>
> - **Per-task, command-line host lists (fab mytask:host=host1) override absolutely everything else.**
> - Per-task, decorator-specified host lists (@hosts('host1')) override the env variables.
> - Globally specified host lists set in the fabfile (env.hosts = ['host1']) can override such lists set on the command-line, but only if you’re not careful (or want them to.)
> - Globally specified host lists set on the command-line (--hosts=host1) will initialize the env variables, but that’s it.

Give that first option a try, and let us know if you have any other questions.